# Cannot test laravel livewire model hidden attribute with assertSet

Tags: laravel, testing, hidden, laravel-livewire, laravel-models

I have a simple LIvewire component consisting of a form to create a new User, and it work, i can tell since i've been asked to write tests after the project already reached staging.

The Livewire component use a `new User` instance (non presisted, i.e. `user->exists` is `false`) to store inserted data before persisting it, and the `user` model hides the password attribute trough the protected `$hidden` array.

Now, i can sucesfully create new users trough the form page in my local environment, but when it comes to testing, it gives me error.

#### The test

```
Livewire::test(
        FormComponent::class,
    )
    ->set('user.name', 'user name')
    ->set('user.email', 'user@email.com')
    ->set('user.password', 'password')
    ->assertSet('user.name', 'user name')
    ->assertSet('user.email', 'user@email.com')
    ->assertSet('user.password', 'password');
```

#### The error

```
Failed asserting that null matches expected 'password'.
```

#### What i find out

Setting my compoment user instance trough the form page goes fine because livewire recognize it as a `model`, so do something like `user->password = 'password'`, while when setting it from the test with `set()` it access its property with the access operator as it is an array, i.e.: `user['password] = 'password'`.
Commenting out the password entry in the `$hidden` array made the test pass.
This will explain the difference in the property setting.

#### Conclusion

Since the `$hidden` array is meant to hide model properties in its array/json representation it should not interfere with automated tests, moreover when using Livewire own methods, so to me this looks like a LIvewire Bug.

#### Help

Does anyone have aver encountered this bug?

#### Update#1

I've opened an [issue](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2161) on Livewire github page for this.

Answer (score 1):

You have diagnosed this pretty well. When Livewire serializes the User model, `password` is not included because it is in the `$hidden` array. Even though the User model has not been persisted yet, serialization is the same.

I would guess that your input fields all use the `defer` modifier, which is why your fields are working in the browser; however, when you call `set()` in the test, it simulates a Livewire request, so the `$hidden` attributes are being wiped.

An alternate assertion for testing the password is my recommendation here. Try asserting that the created user can login with the selected password.

```php
$this->assertTrue(
    auth()->attempt(['email' => 'user@email.com', 'password' => 'password'])
);
```